# MS Access VBA - Loop Split Function and Output Either First Value (If Not Null) or Last Value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a field in my Access database that contains values such as `24,25,152`, `128,152`, `,113`, `113` and NULLS.

When there is only one value present in the field I would like the first value to be my output (`113` for `,113` and `113`) and when there is more than one value present I would like the last value to be my output (`152` for `24,25,152` and `128,152`).

Right now I have a user-defined function that is invoked by a query that has been hard-coded to account for the correct number of commas/values present in the field. In the future there will be more commas so I would like to account for those and I'd like my output to be in a single column (as opposed to having one column per value after each comma).

Here is VBA code for that user-defined function which came from [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/separate-comma-delimited-field-into-separate/78e97b88-562d-4b39-9706-d633039332f8).

```
Function mySplit(sMyText As String, sDelim As String, lIndx As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    mySplit = Split(sMyText, sDelim)(lIndx)

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        mySplit = ""
    Else
        MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Source: mySplit" & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
               Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
               , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit



End Function
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT Field, mySplit([field].[table],",",0) AS 1, mySplit([field].[table],",",1) AS 2, mySplit([field].[table],",",2) AS 3, Val(IIf([3]<>"",[3],IIf([2]<>"",[2],IIf([1]<>"",[1])))) AS [Value]

FROM Table;
```

Ideally I'd to have a single field that looks like the "Value" field (outlined in green) in the image below.

Right now that value field is a bunch of nested `if` statements looking at the `1`, `2`, and `3` columns. I know I need to modify this code to count the delimiters and then loop through each delimiter and take either the first value (if there is only one) and the last value (if there is more than one) but I am not sure how to go about achieving that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

***EDIT***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Just Split the value and return the last element in the array. If the value is null, return an empty string.

```vb
Public Function SplitToLast(Value As Variant) As String
    On Error GoTo Trap

    If IsNull(Value) Then GoTo Leave

    Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(Value, ",")

    SplitToLast = arr(UBound(arr))

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

Comment: Kostas - this works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Kostas - one quick question. I get a "Subscript out of range" error each time I run the query. I simply hit OK and everything works as expected but I was wondering if you had any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Sounds like one of the supplied values is causing it. It must be only one value so if you can identify which one, we’ll be able to sort it out.

Comment: You are right. In the view I am querying I have 96 records yet the query with your function returns 95. See the image I just added. That last record it weird.

Comment: To clarify that image I added is of the view I am querying. That last record is causing the error. The query that makes use of your function works perfectly except when you scroll down to the last record you get spammed with the "Subscript out of range" error message.

Comment: It shouldn't throw an error if null or even white-space. Set a beakpoint just before you reach the last record and see the value supplied to the function.

Comment: NVM I just wrapped the expression in an IF "" THEN "" ELSE [your function] and that fixed it. Kostas thank you again this was really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Public Function GetLastValue(ByVal value As Variant, ByVal delimiter As String) As String
    If IsNull(value) Then Exit Function

    If Len(delimiter) = 0 Then
        GetLastValue = value
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim tmpValue As String
    tmpValue = Trim(CStr(value))

    Do While tmpValue Like "*" & delimiter
        tmpValue = Trim(Left(tmpValue, Len(tmpValue) - Len(delimiter)))
    Loop

    If Len(tmpValue) = 0 Then Exit Function

    Dim tmpArr() As String
    tmpArr = Split(tmpValue, delimiter)

    GetLastValue = tmpArr(UBound(tmpArr))
End Function
```

- It also takes care of multiple delimiters at the end of the value like `1,2,3,, ,`.
- It also works if the length of the delimiter is > 1.
- In case `value` is an empty string, the result will be an empty string too.
- In case `delimiter` is an empty string, the result will be `value`.

This example calling works fine:

`SELECT GetLastValue([Field1],",") AS LastValue FROM Table1`

If you edit the query in the query design view and not in SQL view, take care of the `,` which separates the parameters. There it must be a `;` instead.

Comment: Unhanded Exception - thank you for the assistance your code looks right but I kept getting a "Undefined function in expression" error. I ended up using Kostas' answer.

Comment: No problem. This seems to be because of possible Null-values in your data. I will correct that.

Comment: Yes I did. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't understand correctly. Ideas for what? Did you try the current code? Does it still not work?

Comment: Sorry yes I did try the updated code and I still get the "Undefined function in expression" error.